# Listing all LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress calls in a PE file

Tags: c++, c, portable-executable

I need a sample code/tools which parses the PE file and lists all `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` calls. Along with that I also need the DLL name passed to `LoadLibrary` and function name passed to each of the listed `GetProcAddress` calls.

Comment: In full generality what you ask for is effectively impossible to achieve with static analysis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to statically check for the calls made to LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.

To get a list of imports and exports from the PE file statically, use PEDUMP (or you can use this online utility: http://pedump.me).

To profile an application for LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress you'll want something like WinDbg. Attach WinDbg to the process you want to profile and put a breakpoint on LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress. You'll then be able to see the parameter. For example:

- bp kernel32!LoadLibraryA "da poi(esp+4); g;"

will print out all calls to LoadLibraryA as they happen.

Comment: FWIW, [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) provides an easier way to profile the LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress calls.

Comment: You can't get *every* possibility (some instances may be too dynamic), but I wouldn't say "There is no way to statically check...". There may be plenty of cases where the arguments are constant and detectable through static analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). This tool shows the all types (implicit, delay-loaded, forwarded) dependencies. Using this tool you can even test the dynamic dependencies (the ones that are made by invoking LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress)! To make the later, you must run Dependency walker in profiling mode.

Comment: oops, just see that Dependency Walker is mentioned in the comment above!

Comment: You can also try PeStudio (www.winitor.com) to see these (static) dependies and many other information located in PE files.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases on 64-bit Windows you won't be able to use Dependency Walker. In that case use this in WinDbg:

```
bu KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW "du/c100 rcx;g;"
```